# On projection of fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is it true that the positive part i.e $\sum_{n}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ of the  Fourier series of $f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$ defines a function in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$?

I  don't think so, but cant come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Does "defines" mean converges a.e. to a function in $L^\infty$? Or do you need the function to be defined everywhere and actually bounded?

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy the first

Comment: This is unclear. Do you mean $f \in L^\infty([0,2\pi])$ and its Fourier series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}$ converges pointwise to $f$ then what is $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n e^{inx}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 The question is well formulated. There is no assumption of the Fourier series of $f$ converging. For any $f$ as in the problem you define the coefficients of the series by their integral, then take the series formed by the terms with non-negative exponents. That series converges in the unit disc. The question is if it converges on the circle almost everywhere and if that function is in $L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$. There is a function on $T$ defined by the radial limits of $g$ and that function is in $L^\infty(T)$.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy  If the series diverges then it won't define a function. The OP didn't mention a.e. convergence

Comment: Yes, he/she clarified after my first comment. You don't need convergence everywhere to define an $L^{\infty}$ function.

Comment: The radial limits of those functions $g$ are functions in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$. Those functions form the subspace $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})$. I don't know, and that seems to be the OP's question, what happens to the sum of the series on $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy that is correct

Comment: Of course the Fourier series of $f$ converges a.e. on the circle, as does the projected Fourier series, by Carleson's theorem. But we don't need this powerful (and difficult) result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is well known, the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (nt)}{n }$$

converges pointwise everywhere, and in $L^2,$ to a bounded function $f.$ We can write

$$f(t)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{e^{int}-e^{-int}}{2i}.$$

The projected Fourier series of $f$ then looks like

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{e^{int}}{2i}.$$

That's a constant times $\log (1-e^{it}).$

Comment: To the down voter: Why?

Comment: I guess one has to show that the projected Fourier series does not represent $L^{\infty}(T)$ function.