# Projection to positive Fourier coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-series

$\newcommand{\A}{A({\mathbb D})}\newcommand{\C}{C({\mathbb T})}$Let $\C$ the Banach space consisting of all complex
valued, continuous functions on the unit circle $\mathbb T$ under the sup norm.  The disk algebra $\A$ is an intensely
studied  subspace of $\C$ which can be defined in three equivalent ways:

1. The closed subspace of $\C$ spanned by the functions $z\mapsto z^n$, for $n\geq 0$.
2. The subset of $\C$ formed by all functions $f$ with vanishing negative
   Fourier coefficients,  that is,
   $$
     \hat f(n)=0,\quad\forall n<0.
     $$
3. The subset of $\C$ formed by all functions $f$ admitting a continuous extension $\tilde f$ to the closed unit disk $\mathbb D$,
   such that $\tilde f$ is
   holomorphic on the interior of $\mathbb D$.

It is a fact that $\A$ is not complemented in $\C$ in the sense that there is no closed subspace $E\subseteq \C$ such that
$$
  \C=\A\oplus E.
  $$

This can be shown to be equivalent to the following statement: There exists a doubly infinite sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=-\infty }^\infty $, such that
$$
  \sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty a_n e^{int}
  $$
is the Fourier series of a continuous, $2 \pi $-periodic function, while the positive part of this series, namely
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{int}
  $$
is not.

**Question**.  What is a concete example  of a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=-\infty }^\infty $, as above?

---

**NOTES**

See [On projection of fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327267/on-projection-of-fourier-series) for the corresponding result
regarding $L^\infty(\mathbb T)$.

I found two proofs  of the fact that $\A$ is not complemented in $\C$, which would in theory be enough to provide an
answer to my question, but I was unable to make it work.  These proofs can be found in:

1. Page 137 of *Rudin, Walter*, Functional analysis, McGraw-Hill Series in Higher Mathematics. New York etc.: McGraw-Hill Book Comp. XIII, 397 p. (1973). [ZBL0253.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0253.46001).
2. Page 55 of *Hoffman, K.*, Banach spaces of analytic functions, Prentice-Hall Series in Modern Analysis. Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice-Hall, Inc. XIII, 217 p. (1962). [ZBL0117.34001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0117.34001).

Comment: I find this question really interesting, but unfortunately I haven’t a clue about the answer. Can you tell me something about the proof of the equivalence you mention? I am talking about the fact that $A(D)$ is not complemented if and only if there if a Fourier series with the property you described. Is this obvious? It does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: Dear @Giuseppe, thanks for your interest.  The hardest, and most interesting direction, is to show that if $A(\mathbb D)$
is complemented,  then   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{int}$ is the Fourier series of a continuous function.  This  is
proved as follows:  the existence of a suplement is equivalent  to  the existence  of a bounded projection
  $$
  P:C(\mathbb T)\to  A(\mathbb D).
  $$
  [to be continued]

Comment: One may then average $P$ along   the action of $\mathbb T$ on $C(\mathbb T)$ by rotation.  The averaged operator will then
be another projection which must send a function $f\sim\sum_{n=-\infty }^\infty a_n e^{int}$  to  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n
e^{int}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick $b_n$ decreasing to zero, $nb_n \to 0, \sum b_n =\infty$; for example $b_n=\frac{1}{n\log n}, n \ge 2$ will do.

Then it is not hard to show that $g(x)=\sum_{n \ge 2} b_n\sin nx$ is continuous on the reals since the series converges uniformly everywhere.

(the result is true but requires a summation by part and a classical estimate on the partial sums of $\sum \sin nx$ in general when $nb_n \to 0$ but not necessarily monotonically, however for the specific case above where $nb_n$ decreases to zero, it immediately follows from the Abel-Dirichlet convergence criterion for series since it is well known that $\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{\sin nx}{n}$ has partial sums uniformly bounded in $x$)

However $h(x)=\sum_{n \ge 2} b_n \cos nx$ is not continuous since the series is divergent to $\infty$ at $0$ and $h$ is continuous on $(0, 2\pi)$ but unbounded (though integrable of course) at $0$

But then taking $f(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z, |n| \ge 2}(-i(\text {sign n}) {b_{|n|}})e^{inx}=2g(x)$ is continuous, but its projection is obviously not since its imaginary part is not by the above

Comment: Otherwise $\frac{ \log(1-z)}{\sqrt{10 - \log(1-z)}}$ (whose imaginary part is continuous on $|z|=1$) ?

Comment: Thanks @Conrad.  Sounds like it is the most elementary example one can cook up, is it?

Comment: I think so - if you find coefficients for which one of the sine or cosine series gives a continuous function and the other doesn't, you get a simple counterexample as above, and usually it is easier to make the sine Fourier series uniformly convergent because of the $0$ at $0$